# How do I pass in the variant property of the material-ui TextField from a wrapping React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm having typing problems...

Basically I have a wrapping React component for the @material-ui TextField but I can't get the typings right for the variant property.

Here's the gist of the issue. @material-ui/core at 3.9.3

```
import MuiTextField, {TextFieldProps} from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

interface MyTextFieldProps {
...
  variant?: TextFieldProps["variant"];
}

class MyTextField extends React.Component<MyTextFieldProps> {
...
  render() {

    return
    ...other stuff
      <MuiTextField
      variant={this.props.variant} />
    ...;
  }
}
```

For the MuiTextField instance I get the following compile error:
...

```
Types of property 'variant' are incompatible.
        Type '"outlined" | "filled"' is not assignable to type '"outlined"'.
          Type '"filled"' is not assignable to type '"outlined"'.
```

I can condense this further into just the prop types:

```
xx() {
    const variant: TextFieldProps["variant"] = this.props.variant;
    const props : TextFieldProps = {
      variant,
    };
}
```

and get the same error that the variant value (which is typed to the exact type of the variant property) is not compatible with its own type.

What is going on here?

The definitions in TextField.d.ts look like this:

```
export interface StandardTextFieldProps extends BaseTextFieldProps {
  variant?: 'standard';
  InputProps?: Partial<StandardInputProps>;
  inputProps?: StandardInputProps['inputProps'];
}

export interface FilledTextFieldProps extends BaseTextFieldProps {
  variant: 'filled';
  InputProps?: Partial<FilledInputProps>;
  inputProps?: FilledInputProps['inputProps'];
}

export interface OutlinedTextFieldProps extends BaseTextFieldProps {
  variant: 'outlined';
  InputProps?: Partial<OutlinedInputProps>;
  inputProps?: OutlinedInputProps['inputProps'];
}

export type TextFieldProps = StandardTextFieldProps | FilledTextFieldProps | OutlinedTextFieldProps;
```

### Update

As Daniel points out, this is Typescript not knowing how to handle the union type.

You can work around this (ugly) with a helper function like this

```
import { TextFieldProps, BaseTextFieldProps } from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const getProps = (
  baseProps: BaseTextFieldProps,
  variant: TextFieldProps["variant"]
): TextFieldProps => {
  switch (variant) {
    case "filled":
      return { ...baseProps, variant };
    case "outlined":
      return { ...baseProps, variant };
    default:
      return { ...baseProps, variant };
  }
};
```

and then use it as `<TextField ...getProps({value:"text"}, variant) />` but it is ugly.

I would even venture as to classify this is a typescript issue since it should be able to figure out that all props unique to the different variants are optional.

Comment: please provide the sample demo

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same problem.

The reason for the error is that they've defined

`TextFieldProps = StandardTextFieldProps | FilledTextFieldProps | OutlinedTextFieldProps`

OutlinesTextFieldProps needs a value of 'outlined' for variant
FilledTextFieldProps needs a value of 'filled' for variant

etc.

The issue is that the value of variant is not known at compile time. In your code it's a variable so its type is `'filled' | 'outlined'`. That type is incompatible with any of the three type definitions, which each require one of 'outlined', 'filled' or 'standard'

Apart from the `as any` trick, the only other option I can think of is to instantiate textfeilds with static values for variant, but this is a lot of extra work. Something like:

```
{ this.props.variant === 'outlined' && (
  <MuiTextField
    variant="outlined"
   />
)}
{ this.props.variant === 'filled' && (
  <MuiTextField
    variant="filled"
   />
)}
```

edit - 03/06/2019

There was a bug raised on the material-ui github and another possible solution was posted

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15697#issuecomment-493419773

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was going insane :)

Comment: @Daniel van Berzon Would you mind sharing a link to a github issue that you've filed?

Comment: @JosiahNunemaker Apologies, I never got round to it! I'll try and do one today and link you in

Comment: @JosiahNunemaker I found this closed ticket that highlights the same issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15697

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the correct approach, but to solve it for now you can cast it to `any`.

```
variant={this.props.variant as any}
```

I have the same issue as of now and could not find a way to solve it the typescript way.